# A pdf foxit file with comments and highlights on it is overwritten by latex and thus I lost the comments. Where can I recover the previous pdf file?

Tags: pdf, data-recovery, latex, file-recovery, foxit-reader

A foxit reader pdf file with comments on it is just overwritten by a compile on TeXstudio and thus I lost the comments. Where can I recover the previous pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Shadow Copy enabled, you can try right-clicking the file and opening the `Restore previous versions` dialog:

[image]

If you have no other backup or snapshot service set up, your only hope would be a file recovery utility such as [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva).

Comment: if the file was saved in a Dropbox folder, then Dropbox will have previous versions saved also

Comment: I have "Restore previous versions" when I right click on the file but then in the box it says "there are no previous versions available".

Comment: Then sorry to say, you're out of luck on that route (unless you're in a business environment. In that case contact your IT helpdesk; they may have Shadow Copy set up server-side). Only thing left is to try Recuva.

Comment: And Recuva couldn't find the pdf file.

Comment: I'm out of suggestions, sorry.